# A lock-free queue's push operation using compare_exchange_weak

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, compare-and-swap, stdatomic

I've come across a lock-free queue that supports multi-producer and a consumer, the push operation of the queue goes like this

```
inline void push(LT* item)
{

    LT *old = pushlist.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    do {
        item->next = old;
    } while (!pushlist.compare_exchange_weak(old, item, 
                                             std::memory_order_release));
}
```

`pushlist` is an atomic pointer-variable and I am thinking about a scenario where two threads are on this code

Thread1 :

- T1# Loads the pointer (won't LOCK# anything)
- **T2#** Goes to loop and hook the head (`old`) into new item
- T3# Now in the cmpxchg(LOCK#); it expects head (`old`) to be * this-- which is true, so swap will be successful

Thread2:

- **T2#** Loads the pointer (won't LOCK# anything)
- T3# Goes to loop and hook the head (`old`) into its new item
- T4# Now cmpxchg will expect head (`old`) to be * this-- which is not I guess, because Thread1 already changed it, so `old` isn't the head anymore, operation will be unsuccessful......now, will it not going to spin?

I tested it, works fine, yet I am not clear how it does.

```
auto work = [&p](auto name){
    int i{0};
    linked_item<int> dummy{};
    for(; i < 100 ; ++i){
        p.push(&dummy);
    }
    std::cout<<name<<" finished"<< i << "\n";
};
std::thread t1{work, "t1"}, t2{work, "t2"};
t1.join(); t2.join();
```

Comment: At `T4`, if `pushlist.load != old`, the first argument (`old`, an lvalue reference) will be updated to the current value of `pushlist` and it should work the second attempt.

Comment: Agree. I missed reading that part in cpp reference.

Comment: *Unless you want an answer about a specific C++ version that is not the most recent one, and only that one, you don't need a C++ version tag like [tag:c++11].* I have replaced it with the [tag:c++] as ppl are more likely to watch that general tag.